# how to stack 2d tensor to 3d tensor in required dimension?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a 2d tensor of shape [32,768] also a 3d tensor of [32,512,768]. I want the stack them and get output to have shape of [32,512,1536].

If I expand dimensions at axis=1 for 2d and concat. I am getting [32,513,768]. So how to get [32,512,1536] as my output shape of tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you will have to repeat the 2D tensor along axis 1 512 times to get a 3D tensor of shape [32, 512, 768]. This 3D tensor when concatenated with the other 3D tensor along the last dimension will give a tensor of shape [32, 512, 1536]. You need to make sure this repetition in desired.

Longer extension:

Let's take a much simpler case:

Take a 1D tensor `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Say you need to concatenate this to a 2D tensor of shape [2, 5], say `((6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15))`. Note that this is a simplified version of your problem, with smaller tensors and no batch dimension.

One way to combine these tensors is to get a tensor of shape [3, 5]. Here, you would expand the 1D tensor to a 2D tensor having shape [1, 5], and concatenate along axis 0. This will give the result `((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15))`. When applied to your problem, this gives the resulting [32, 513, 768] tensor you have.

The second way would give the tensor `((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15))`, having shape [2, 10]. As you can see, this requires `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` to be repeated twice. So, you'll have to expand the 1D tensor to get the shape [1, 5], and repeat it to get a tensor of shape [2, 5]. This tensor can then be concatenated with the other 2D tensor. In your case, you will expand the 2D tensor to shape [32, 1, 768], then repeat it 512 times along axis 1 to get a tensor of shape [32, 512, 768], which will be concatenated with the other 3D tensor.

When going for the second method, ensure that you really want to repeat the smaller tensor across all entries of the second tensor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import torch

a = torch.ones([32,768])
b = torch.ones([32,512,768])
result = torch.cat([a[:, None, :].repeat(1, 512,1), b], dim=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The aim should be to both have same dimension, and then the `torch.cat` would work:

```
import torch
a = torch.ones([32,768])
b = torch.ones([32,512,768])

result = torch.cat((a.view(b.shape[0],b.shape[1],1),b),dim=-1)
```

In this case you will have the output in a 3D format.